# Update on dulipcate entry while Import Excel file - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, sql-update, insert-update

I need to check if value inserting in database while **import excel file** , if it has already value in database then it should get update.

***Below is producttab table value in database***

```
prdid | prdname 
00A   |  prd1
00B   |  prd2
00C   |  prd3
00D   |  prd4
```

**Below is EXCEL FILE data**

```
prdid | prdname 
00A   |  prdnew
00B   |  prd2new
00E   |  prd8
00H   |  prd9
```

So if i upload above excel file then ,

00A , 00B should get UPDATE IN  producttab table as they are already present there... but 00E,00H should get insert

*below is what i have tried, value is getting insert properly
only UPDATE IS NOT HAPPENING, i means IF..ELSE condition is perfect, only UPDATE is not going proper  *

```
if(isset($_POST["Upload"]))
{
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);

    $filetype = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"];
    $remark = NULL;

    //Validate File Type
    if(strtolower(trim($fileinfo["extension"])) != "csv")
    {
        $_SESSION['msg_r'] = "Please select CSV file";
        header("location:importfile.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $file_path = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"];
    }

$row = 0;

$tempFileName = time().".csv";

if ( is_uploaded_file( $file_path ) ) {
    $fileCopied = copy( $file_path , $tempFileName);


if (($handle = fopen($tempFileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 6000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }

$col1 = $col[0]; // prdid
$col2 = $col[1]; // prdname   

$sql = "SELECT prdid FROM producttab WHERE prdid = '".$col1."' ";
$query = db_query($sql);
$pfetech = db_fetch($query);

// ABOVE select QUERY IS PERFECT , it taking me to if conditions 

if($col1 == $pfetech['prdid']){

  // only below update not happening 

    $sqlup = "UPDATE producttab 
              SET prdid = ".$pfetech['prdid'].",
                  prdname = ".$col2."  ";
    $sqlup .= " WHERE prdid = ".$pfetech['prdid']." ";    
    $resultsqlupdate = mysql_query($sqlup);

}else{    

$query = "INSERT INTO producttab(prdid,prdname) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2.")"; 
$s = mysql_query($query);

}


 }
    fclose($handle);
}
    echo "<center>File data imported to database!!</center>";                            
 }
} 

}
```

**Below is print/echo of UPDATE query ,**

```
update producttab set prdname='prdnew' WHERE prdid='00A'
update producttab set prdname='prd2new' WHERE prdid='00B'
```

Value for prdname is shown proper as per excel file .... only update is not happening ....

Comment: anyone here ...please let me what is issue ....

Comment: u can use exists query then u can update or insert on the basis of if decision .

Comment: u means to say IN CLAUSE ?? ...but how i can as $col1 value coming like ... 00A00B ...together ...can u please help me

Comment: You can user INSERT IGNORE clause, and create unique index on the columns that are identifying a row.

Comment: Hi Afshan, thanks for reply but i want to UPDATE ON THAT prdid only ..for future use ...thats when i had insert value in database and when i did updates...etc many records ...hence doing update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use exists query to check whether is exists or not in database , following is query

```
 select  exists(select 1 from producttab where prdid='".$col1."');
```

it will give u 1 if it exits and 0 if not then do further insertion or updation on the if else condition

and only set one thing not other like this

```
  "UPDATE producttab 
          SET  prdname = ".$col2."
  $sqlup .= " WHERE prdid = ".$pfetech['prdid']." ";
```

oh sorry u need to update prdname not prdid .
edited my answer

ps. 
u should use mysql import from csv query for this 
here is link for help 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: Hi Asad , thanks for answer ... but problem is not about selecting ..the problem is about UPDATE ... when  i echo/print my update query ...it result as below ... update producttab set prdid='00A'  WHERE prdid='00A' update producttab set prdid='00B'  WHERE prdid='00B'... dont know what going wrong ..

Comment: sorry @user3209031 u need to update prdname not prdid , Ive edited it

Comment: i DID ... but not working i am getting message " File data imported to database!! " but in database VALUE IS NOT UPDATE ..I MEANS prdname is not updated ..it showing same old value of it

Comment: exists query working for you or not ? its a query to check whether a record is exists in data base or not

Comment: any idea why its not updating ...but if i echo/print my update query ....its showing me ... update producttab set prdname='prdnew' WHERE prdid='00A' update producttab set prdname='prd2new' WHERE prdid='00B' .... but value is not update in database ...but but ..if i copy this query and do from phpmyadmin sql update ...then value is UPDATE ...

Comment: yes EXISTS query ..and my select query working fine ..means ...if same value ( 00A==00A) then it take me in update  loop ... as u see i have echo/print my update query and value its shows me s.. and this value is not inserted in database again ...

Comment: update producttab set prdname='prdnew' WHERE prdid='00A' 
update producttab set prdname='prd2new' WHERE prdid='00B'   .... this is what echo/print my update query shows....but in database value is not updating ...

Comment: you sould add semicolon `;` after first query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114815/discussion-between-asad-and-user3209031).